# Perl - How to remove new lines stored in perl hash?

Tags: perl

Currently I am stuck with this problem when i use datadumper to print my perl hash which I imported from a spreadsheet, some of the hash print into multiple lines with carriage return symbol(^M) as source cell had new line in it. I have managed to remove the carriage symbol, but those new lines still persists. I have tried doing this to my string, it only manages to remove carriage return symbol ^M, but new lines still exist.

```
$title = $sheet->{Cells}[0][$col]{Val};
$num = $sheet->{Cells}[$row+1][$col]{Val};

$title =~ s/\r//g;
$num =~ s/\r//g;
$title2 = chomp($title);
$num2 = chomp($num);
```

The output i get when i print is this

```
$VAR1 = {
          '' => {
                  'JOHN
has a car' => {
                             'SUV' => A red coloured
2022 suv from
japan
```

I expect to get

```
$VAR1 = {
          '' => {
                  'JOHN' => {
                             'SUV' => A red coloured 2022 suv from japan
```

Comment: How do you import your spreadsheet? The easiest way to do this is to process each cell as it is being read.

Comment: You probably want to remove newlines too.

Comment: You could use [`\R`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash#%5CR) instead of `\r`, that should handle any likely combination of carriage return and newline.

Comment: @JimDavis - You should elevate your comment to a full answer.

Comment: "When I print". When you print what? $title2 should not contain what you show here, since chomp does not return the string itself. So what exactly are you printing? If $sheet is an object it is not certain you can apply a regex to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`\R`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash#%5CR) instead of `\r`, that should handle any likely combination of carriage return and newline.  It was released in Perl 5.10:

> `\R` matches a generic newline; that is, anything considered a linebreak sequence by Unicode. This includes all characters matched by `\v` (vertical whitespace), and the multi character sequence "`\x0D\x0A`" (carriage return followed by a line feed, sometimes called the network newline; it's the end of line sequence used in Microsoft text files opened in binary mode). `\R` is equivalent to `(?>\x0D\x0A|\v)`.